# AggregateByKey on a pairRDD of Strings to get List of Strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a pairRDD of type [String, String]. The first column represents the key and the second column represents the value. I need to aggregate the RDD so that I get a String -> List[String] which I can later collectAsMap. For instance, I've a pairRDD of the form:

```
A,a
B,b
A,c
A,d
B,e
C,c
D,f
C,b
```

I've used aggregateByKey in the past for counting instances of words which meant just adding the values. However, I can't figure out how I will be able to get a list of strings out of a string.

After applying aggregateByKey, it should look something like:

```
A,[a,c,d]
B,[b,e]
C,[c,b]
D,[f]
```

{Order doesn't matter, it's okay if the order of the keys and/or the values is jumbled.}

I want to later collect the pairRDD as a map of type [String, List[String]]. I need the map for an important post-processing step.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `groupByKey` and `mapValues`

```
val map = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(_.toList).collectAsMap()
```

Gives you `Map[String, List[String]]`

If you still want to use `aggregateByKey` then

```
rdd.aggregateByKey(List[String]())(
  (acc, x) => x :: acc,
  (acc1, acc2) => acc1 ::: acc2
)
```

Output:

```
(B,List(b, e))
(A,List(a, c, d))
(C,List(c, b))
(D,List(f))
```

Comment: When I do rdd.collectAsMap, it only gives me a map of type [String, String] and not [String, List[String]], as I wanted. How can I get a map of type [String, List[String]]? I need the map for an important post processing step. This whole rdd processing was just so I could get a map at the end. If you've another method to obtain the said map that doesn't involve rdds, that'll work too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `collectAsMap` should give you `Map[String, List[String]]`